How to perform amplitude amplification to return $|\psi_{\rm good}⟩$ from $\cos\theta|\psi_{\rm good},\phi⟩+\sin\theta|\psi_{\rm bad},\phi^\perp⟩$?
You are given access to a quantum algorithm $A$ that prepares a state
$$|\psi\rangle=cos\theta|\psi_{good}\rangle|\phi\rangle+sin\theta|\psi_{bad}\rangle|\phi^{\perp}\rangle$$
Where $|\phi\rangle=\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}|0^n\rangle+\epsilon|0^{n\perp}\rangle$ and $\epsilon=O(2^{-n})$
Above, $|\psi_{good}\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|\psi_{bad}\rangle$ and both are valid quantum states. $|\phi\rangle,|\phi^\perp\rangle$ are orthogonal to one another. Unlike a typical amplitude amplification procedure, you have no direct means of distinguishing $|\psi_{good}\rangle$ from $|\psi_{bad}\rangle$.

Show that $|\psi\rangle$ is a valid quantum state.
Devise a procedude for returning $|\psi_{good}\rangle$ with very high probability and quantify the probability. (Hint: you'll want to exploit entanglement).

I have made some progress regarding question 1 solving for the normalization of |$\psi\rangle$:
$$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=(cos\theta\langle\psi_{good}|\langle\phi|+sin\theta\langle\psi_{bad}|\langle\phi^\perp|)(cos\theta|\psi_{good}\rangle|\phi\rangle+sin\theta|\psi_{bad}\rangle|\phi^\perp\rangle)$$
Reduces to:
$$=cos^2\theta\langle\psi_{good}|\psi_{good}\rangle\langle\phi|\phi\rangle+sin^2\theta\langle\psi_{bad}|\psi_{bad}\rangle\langle\phi^\perp|\phi^\perp\rangle
= cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta=1$$
Therefore proving that $|\psi\rangle$ is a valid quantum state.
As for question 2, I consider trying to perform a measurement on the second register to distinguish between $\phi$ and $\phi^\perp$, however I am not sure if I am actually able to do this. Any help is appreciated.

@MarkSpinelli I updated the question with progress, any help is appreciated.

For question 1 - A state is a valid quantum state if it is normalised (i.e. the sum of the absolute value of its coefficients squared add to 1).
For question 2 - This question is basically asking you to derive Amplitude Amplification but with a twist. Read the following presentation from slides 3/39 to 16/39 https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wK2P0FwKuhPOvZgSii1QH_QlMPmuTxJ/view?usp=sharing to understand amplitude amplification, and then think about how you would modify it given that the setup is a little bit different.
